# How to delay swift property didSet so it only fires once per second

Tags: swift

Would it be possible to limit didSet, so it only fires once in a time interval, like once every second, and not multiple times in a second? Like some kind of debounce method?

```
@Published var someProperty: String = "" {didSet {
    Task {
        await someFunction(someParamater: someProperty)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `@Published` property has a Combine publisher under the hood. You can subscribe to this publisher and debounce it like this:

```swift
myModel.$someProperty
    .debounce(...)
    .sink { value in
        // Do what you wanted to do in didSet
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Swift and was hoping to not have to crack into the hell of Combine... but here I am.